# Select doesn't work from windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, select, sql-server-ce

I want to check if the data about a file exists in table

```
public bool ExistFile(string name)
{

    bool result = false;
    SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = 
              ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    con.Open();

    var command = new SqlCeCommand("Select * From Files
                                         Where nameFile='"+ name +" ' ",con);

    int returnValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Dispose();
    con.Close();

    if (returnValue > 0)
        result = true;
    else
        result = false;

    return result;
}
```

In variable "name" I'm sending existing string in table, but "returnValue" is always -1.
In testQuery panel it works, I'm copying the same query and it works, return value is one row.
Where is the problem, how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure about that whitespace after name + "  ?

Comment: Where nameFile='"+ name +" ' ".... fix your space here..

Comment: You have an extra space in after name.  `nameFile='"+ name +" '` should be `nameFile='"+ name +"'`.  However, you should be using parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: You're using the wrong method: [`SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.executenonquery(v=vs.80).aspx): "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other DML statements, the return value is -1."

Comment: Also, don't `SELECT *` (or even `SELECT COUNT(*)`) when all you care about is whether rows exist or not - use the `EXISTS` predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want to check if a record exists, you don't need to return any fields from your query. You can write it like this, using [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.executescalar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
var command = new SqlCeCommand("select 1 as Result from Files where nameFile = @file",con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", name);
var result=command.ExecuteScalar();
```

This will return just a single value instead of the entire record

Just make sure the `name` variable doesn't contain any unwanted whitespaces like your original example.

Comment: OP will also need to change the check on the return value :)

Answer (score 4):

Better approach would be this:

```
var command = new SqlCeCommand("select top 1 * from Files where nameFile = @file",con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", name);

var returned = command.ExecuteScalar();

if (returned != null)
{
    returned = true;
}
```

and this should work fine. Also `top 1` is for performance if you only want to check if file exists in database.

Comment: @alex Don't check the return Value, check the query's results! No records are ever affected by a query

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a space after name - in other words, say name = "John", but in the query it will be 'John '.  That's probably why it's not working.

Additionally, you should use a parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection attacks.  Something like this should fix your issue:

```
var command = new SqlCeCommand("Select * From Files
                                     Where nameFile=@Name",con);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please always use [`parameterized SQL`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
var command = new SqlCeCommand("Select * From Files Where nameFile= @nameFile",con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameFile", name);

int returnValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```